# Is it possible to make jQuery only target div for hover animation if it is a child of the element being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Okay, I am a beginner at Javascript and jQuery, so this may be a very simple question, but I've tried researching it, and can't quite find any good answers.

On my website:

http://joeyellisdesign.com/testingspace/JE2

I have a rollover on the "work" section of my portfolio that I am trying to make only appear when you hover over the individual image.

To set up the animation, I have this code:

```
jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".project").hover(function(){
$(".projectdescription").animate({top:'4px'});
},function(){
$(".projectdescription").animate({top:'183.77px'});
});
});
```

Also, here is the CSS and HTML.

```
<div class="project">
<a class="workanchor" href="#">
<img src="files/workthumbs/finsons.jpg">
<div class="projectdescription">
<h4>FINSON'S BEARD PRODUCTS</h4>
<p>Packaging and Identity</p>
<img class="plus" src="files/plus.png" width="129" height="129">
</div>
</a>
</div>


.project {
width: 295px;
height: 240px;
margin: 0px 1.25% 7%;
padding: 0px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
} 
#workcontainer .project .projectdescription {
background: #FFF;
margin: -4px 0px 0px;
padding: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 240px;
position: absolute;
top: 183.77px;
} 
#work #workwrapper #workcontainer .project .workanchor .projectdescription .plus {
margin: 30px 0px 0px 83px;
padding: 0px;
height: 129px;
width: 129px;
```

}

Thanks in advance for any and all help/and/or information that I know nothing. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".project").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
     $(".projectdescription", this).animate({top: e.type=='mouseenter' ? '4px' : '183.77px'});
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8uPPy/)

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect and you're my bestfriend.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$(".project").hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".projectdescription").animate({top:'4px'});
},function(){
    $(this).find(".projectdescription").animate({top:'183.77px'});
});
```